# Apache QPID JMS proxy support

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I need to find whether Apache QPID JMS (AMQP 1.0) supports connection via a proxy like HTTP. Can anybody please help in finding this as I can not see any documentation for this in QPID?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does since 0.47.

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.47.0/release-notes.html

> New features and improvements
> QPIDJMS-441 - Using QPID JMS behind a proxy

this has been implemented in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPIDJMS-441

please check this code : https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/blob/master/qpid-jms-client/src/test/java/org/apache/qpid/jms/integration/ProxyIntegrationTest.java#L77